# Monitors can not detect signal on HP display dock G2

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am using HP Probook 450 G10 (i5-1335u), with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and trying to connect to a HP USB-C/A Universal Dock G2 that is connected to 2 monitors from DisplayPort ports. When I plugged in using both USB-C port in my laptop, I can still connect to ethernet and charge my computer, but the monitors seem to cannot detect any output signal (the light of the dock is on). What should be the problem and how can I fix it? (I am dual-booting with Windows 11 and it seems to work with Windows 11, though sometime the same problem happens)

Answer (score 0):

Usually to have this working (that's sort of my config) you need to install the last synaptic drivers :

https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Hope that will fix your issue

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That actually helps me with this. Usually it just works well with a normal monitor, but it did not work for display docks before I tried your approach.